# Revenuecat REST API - When recording a purchase got Content-Type not application/json

Tags: api, rest, content-type, revenuecat

I'm trying to use POST methods (Revenue REST API) but I always get the error message "Content-Type not application/json".

```
The strange is that I'm using their website to test: [https://docs.revenuecat.com/reference#receipts][1]
```

[API TEST (IMAGE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1To1G.png)

```
curl --request POST \
     --url https://api.revenuecat.com/v1/receipts \
     --header 'Accept: application/json' \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --header 'X-Platform: android' \
     --data '
{
     "product_id": "xxxx",
     "price": 12.9,
     "currency": "BRL",
     "is_restore": "false",
     "app_user_id": "xxxx",
     "fetch_token": "xxxxxx"
}
'
```

Any clues?

Comment: Hard to be 100% sure, but nothing stands out to me as obviously wrong. Might be time to contact support. In the future _please_ share code not pictures.

Comment: Thanks Evert. I've already contact them. As soon as they contatc me I will post here. I've post the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've run the code using CURL and it works. Problem was in revenuecat website.

Answer (score 0):

Their API test page has a bug. It adds an extra `Content-Type: application/json`
header to the request. You can see it the `Metadata` tab

```
Request Headers

Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
X-Platform: stripe
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ********************
User-Agent: ReadMe-API-Explorer
```

And sends the request with an invalid header (you can check it in your browsers network traffic):

```
content-type: application/json, application/json
```